# Flow: how to extend native JS object (especially Promise)?

Tags: flowtype

```
// @flow
type Deferred = Promise<any> & {
  reject: Function;
  resolve: Function;
};


/** Deferred based on Promise
@return {Promise} */
export default (): Deferred => {
  let res, rej;
  let deferred: Deferred = Object.assign(
    new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      res = resolve;
      rej = reject;
    }),
    { 'resolve': res, 'reject': rej }
  );

  return deferred;
};
```

Right now this code gives such errors:

- Cannot assign `Object.assign(...)` to `deferred` because:

  - property `reject` is missing in `Promise` [1] but exists in object type [2].
  - property `resolve` is missing in `Promise` [1] but exists in object type [2].
- Property `reject` is missing in `Promise` [1].
- Property `resolve` is missing in `Promise` [1].

And the question is: how to correctly document this code without errors?

Comment: You'd be much better having the deferred be `{ resolve: Function, reject: Function, promise: Promise }` instead of a subclass.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I am mixing promises and deferreds between each other

Answer (score 2):

1. It's not a good idea to use `any`.
2. It's not a good idea to use `Function` because it's just an alias for `any`.
3. It's better not to use `&`: it's broken. Use type spread instead.
4. If you really want to extend `Promise`, just extend it like this https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjaBDAzh0ARAppHgE5F4AmAPACoB8oeAHgC54B2Z2ACkbALYCWGPNToBvRKFABiUhljQAbngBcoABRUAlKAC8dfIRLkRoAD6gFsfmQDcE6aQBWeZE1VqBDctr24CxUkpaMwsrW3t7ZFhWDCYiAFdXWCI1SFYAfndZeSVM9S1dOk9yABpQJxcmPI9+LzIfItrvQtDrbXFJSSiYplAABx4GAE9dUFEAXztO0Ax4vuI1NWzFPDKK1wax+2mB2GGAOmWlUaO8Ken+waHDvGdXE9vK8+n+SHU07TSlvDkVtceNs9QONNECmAALQT7GQ-HJ4Ua7A6nMGQjDQ9a9HSXPbXDHncYRSSnb6zaBuUBaVQGALGYIdToQqEw35KEnxMmg7blPBMeJEVigRkYfGIewYtQBZKqYr1Kn+IxBMRcoXogFMCUkZKc6akXn8wWokWSRCTUXdWKgMgEUasPDwPyGQJqTmIECgeDJADWGEQVsgNxZeDUAEZNPsIWxFgxVKx4rwAEbETbm+R4fZwADmagYmk5bqiRlc0BGGHBCGwaAFkqIvoIAbhIbDEdYUdUsSI-FYGeT0V+acz2dzdkQjD6yV6frQ7N61IVdiAA

```
class Deferred<T> extends Promise<T> {
  #resolve: (T) => Deferred<T> | void;
  #reject: (mixed) => Deferred<T> | void;

  constructor(fn?: (resolve?: (T) => mixed, reject?: (mixed) => mixed) => void) {
    const proxy = {};
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      proxy.resolve = resolve;
      proxy.reject = reject;
      if (fn) fn(resolve, reject);
    });
    this.#resolve = proxy.resolve;
    this.#reject = proxy.reject;
  }

  resolve(result: T): Deferred<T> {
    this.#resolve(result);
    return this;
  }

  reject(error: mixed): Deferred<T> {
    this.#reject(error);
    return this;
  }
};
```